# Design advice: `unique_ptr` and pybind11

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, pybind11

I have a setup in which a resource `R` may be passed through various filters `F` also deriving from `R`. It makes no sense to share ownership of an `R` because the resource is consumed upon retrieval. Some I decided to use `unique_ptr` as follows:

```
struct R{
  virtual int yield() = 0;
};
struct F{
  F(std::unique_ptr<R> r): _r(std::move(r)) {}
  int yield(){return _r->yield() + 1;}
  std::unique_ptr<R> _r;
};
```

except that of course the classes are more interesting. Now I am trying to bind that with pybind11. Pybind seems not to like `unique_ptr`, as stated in the docs. How can I circumvent this? I see to possibilities:

1. Replacing the `std::unique_ptr` by something pybind11 understands. That would mean that on both the C++ and the Python side, an `R` can be fed into `F` although the `R` has already been consumed by some other `F`.

   1. Instead of taking `std::unqique_ptr`, take `R*&`. Then transfer of ownership can be reflected with setting the parameter to zero. Seems not very C++y, though.
2. Writing a wrapper around `F` that needs no `unique_ptr`. This would have the same problem, but only on the Python side. I could implement something taking care of this, probably. Plus, I wouldn't need to change the interface of existing code. Downside, I need to replicate all methods I need.

Both solutions don't seem too appealing. What would be an alternative?

Comment: Does `F` need to own `R`?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that would be ideal.

Comment: The restriction I see is "While returning unique pointers in this way is allowed, it is illegal to use them as function arguments. ... The above signature would imply that Python needs to give up ownership of an object that is passed to this function, which is generally not possible (for instance, the object might be referenced elsewhere)."

Comment: If you want to allow the python side to supply `R`, then you can't have unique ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues of language interop is that you have to obey the data model of *both* languages. Python doesn't have the conception of unique ownership of a resource, which is why pybind doesn't let you have `std::unique_ptr` as parameters exposed to Python.

I think the easiest way would be to use `std::shared_ptr`, but comment that this is only for interop with the Python binding. You can still have `F::F(std::unique_ptr<R> r)` for the C++ side, because there is a converting constructor `std::shared_ptr<R>::shared_ptr(std::unique_ptr<R>)`.